# Access textviews of mutable list items in a recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin

I followed a tutorial for a todolist and wanted to modify it for my needs.
Every list item has a title, a textview that is displaying a number and a checkbox. When added to the list the title the user put in is set as the title, the textview number is "0" and the checkbox is unchecked.
Here is my class for every item:

```
data class Todo(
    val title: String,
    val id: Int,
    var value: Int,
    var isChecked: Boolean = false
)
```

Here is my code for adding an item:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val curTodo = todos[position]
        holder.itemView.apply {
            //Get Textview and Checkbox from item_item.xml (shown in the post)
            val newItemTodoTitle = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvTodoTitle)
            val newItemCheckbox = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.cbDone)
            //Set values for the new item
            newItemTodoTitle.text = curTodo.title
            newItemCheckbox.isChecked = curTodo.isChecked //curTodo.isChecked is defined as false
            //if checked -> uncheck, if unchecked -> check
            newItemCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                curTodo.isChecked = !curTodo.isChecked
            }
        }
    }
```

I also managed to get the values of the first checked item of the list

```
fun getFirstCheckedItem(): Todo? {
    return todos.find { it.isChecked }
}
```

But i want to change the value/number of a todoItem and therefore need a function that has access to the textview and not just the values of an item.

Here is the xml code of a single item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTodoTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cbDone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbDone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!-- android:textAlignment="viewEnd" richtet den Text rechts aus -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvValue"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTodoTitle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tvTodoTitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvTodoTitle"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the code in my Main Activity, which as written in the comments only displays the new number in the top row:

```
//Get textview where user puts in value
val valueFeld = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etValueInput)
//Make integer from number input
val Zahl = valueFeld.text.toString().toInt()
//Get all values from first checked item
val firstChecked = todoAdaptor.getFirstCheckedItem()
//get current number of the item (by default it is 0)
val valueOfCheckedBox = firstChecked.value
//Add the user number input to the item-value
val newValue = valueOfCheckedBox.plus(Zahl)
//value of the item is set to its new value
firstChecked.value = newValue

//I tried to get the textview like this but the new number is always displayed in the top row
val firstLineTextview = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvValue)
firstLineTextview.text = newValue.toString()
```

Another try was to write a new function in my adaptor:

```
fun writeValue(holder: TodoViewHolder, addedValue: String) {
val itemTextview = holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvValue)
itemTextview.text = addedValue
}
```

But this just crashed the app and idk why

Here is a screenshot when i added 1 to the second item (the above code was active so it got displayed in the first row instead of the second row)
[Screenshot of item getting added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBQsX.png)

Screenshots of the code from Tenfour04 + Error-Messages:
[no value passed for position][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6DF4.png

[unresolved reference for data][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMaee.png

Comment: There’s no reason classes outside the adapter class should have to know about its individual views. Your Todo class is your source of truth about the state of the data and carries the info that might be needed from outside the class. Maybe you need to add one more property to it?

Comment: @Tenfour04 So there should be a way to access the textview of an item by using the Todo class? I thought that the Todo class only stores the values and is not directly connected to the layout of the textviews. I thought the textviews are seperately stored in the TodoViewHolder or did I get this wrong?

Comment: No, there should be one more Int or String property in the Todo class. Do not rely on views for storing data. Your Todo class stores the data. The TextView simply gets a copy of the data in `onBindViewHolder`. If you try to store the data in the TextView, it will be lost the moment it scrolls off screen because a RecyclerView *recycles* the views. Aside from that, even outside a RecyclerView it would be bad practice to rely on views for data storage, because that's not their purpose.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thank you for your advice but storing the data in the Todo class works fine i think. The value of every item changes as it should. My problem is that I dont know how to display it in my textview. Should I make another function in my adapter? Should I change something in my onBindViewHolder function?

Comment: It’s not clear to me which piece of data you’re wanting to change and in response to what event you want to change it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Every Todo-item is automatically generated with a textview that displays "0". When you put it in a number in an edittext and press a button it should add the number to the "0" and display it. The adding isn't a problem but i dont manage to display the new number on the correct row. Do you think it is easier to understand if i provide more of my code in the post or maybe less code and more explanations of what i want to do?

Comment: No, that's enough to go on. I can write an answer later today.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could set this up, but I'm going to recommend what I believe is the most robust (easiest to maintain and keep bug-free), even if it is not the most concise.

The Adapter should not be the manager of the data. We want only one class to be responsible for managing data or you end up with spaghetti code that's hard to maintain. So if we follow this principle, we do not modify any properties of your Todo items from inside the Adapter class.

So to do this, we make these changes to the adapter:

- The adapter keeps a `var` list property so the outside class can pass it a new list if the contents have been changed or moved around.
- We add a property for a listener that reacts to check box clicks.

One additional fix you should do is moving the `findViewById` calls into the ViewHolder. The point of a ViewHolder is to make it very fast to reuse views, so we don't want to make it have to search for views every time a view is rebound.

Here's a basic adapter implementation:

```
class TodoAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoViewHolder>() {

    var data: List<Todo> = emptyList()
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    var itemCheckBoxClickListener: ((position: Int, isChecked: Boolean)->Unit)? = null

    inner class TodoViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val title = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvTodoTitle)
        val checkBox = itemView.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.cbDone)
        val value = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvValue)

        fun bind(itemPosition: Int) {
            val item = data[itemPosition]
            title.text = item.title
            checkBox.isChecked = item.isChecked
            value.text = item.value.toString()
       
            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                itemCheckBoxClickListener?.invoke(itemPosition, isChecked)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder() { 
        // probably unchanged from what you have
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(position)
    }
}
```

Notice that we don't modify the Todo item from the OnCheckedChangeListener. We only pass the call along to the outside class via the listener property we have provided. It is up to the outside class to decide what to do when a check box is clicked for an item. So the outside class is what maintains the list and passes along changes. It can either do this by setting a new value to the Adapter's `data` property, or by informing it of the specific row that changed if we are only modifying row (for better performance).

In onCreate() or onViewCreated():

```
val adapter = TodoAdapter()
adapter.data = data // some list property we have in this class is set as initial data
adapter.itemCheckBoxClickListener { position, isChecked ->
    data[position].isChecked = isChecked
    adapter.notifyItemChanged(position) // notify adapter to update that row visually
}
```

Inside your button's click listener:

```
val valueFeld = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etValueInput)
val Zahl = valueFeld.text.toString().toInt()

// We change this part to do it within this class. It should not be the adapter's
// responsibility to find items for you. It only connects data to views. It doesn't
// manage the data.
val (firstCheckedIndex, firstChecked) = data.withIndex.firstOrNull { it.value.isChecked } 
    ?: return@setOnClickListener // nothing to update if nothing checked so exit early

val valueOfCheckedBox = firstChecked.value
val newValue = valueOfCheckedBox.plus(Zahl)
firstChecked.value = newValue

// And now we notify the adapter of the change so it rebinds the corresponding
// view holder:
adapter.notifyItemChanged(firstCheckedIndex)
```

Comment: If you want to take it a step further, it's actually easier to create a ListAdapter instead of RecyclerView.Adapter. Then you are not responsible for notifying the adapter. You just pass it fresh lists of immutable data with whatever changes are necessary, and it detects the changes for you. You can find tutorials about doing it that way. Then you could make your adapter's listener more user friendly--it would pass the item itself instead of the item position.

Comment: Thank you for your answers but i still have some questions! I copied your adapter changes and got no errors. In the onCreate() function I changed the first line to "val adapter = TodoAdaptor(mutableListOf())" cause otherwise i had an error. Then I deleted the second line because i have no inital data. When i copy the rest of your code it says "No value passed for parameter 'position'" and there is an unresolved reference for "data". I dont relly understand how that function is supposed to work so I dont know how to fix those issues and hope you can help me again! :)

Comment: Notice I have no list parameter in the adapter constructor.  `data` isn't the initial data, it is continually the most up-to-date data. It can be an empty list initially and changed to a filled list later. Of course there is an unresolved reference for `data` if you removed the line that declares the `data` property. So don't make those changes to my version of the class and it should be fine. To know how to fix that error, I would have to know which line of code says "no value passed" and what your code looks like there.

Comment: I put your original code in my onCreate() function and made screenshots of the errors i got. They are now at the bottom of my post.